# AngularJS cumulating style from different directives on an element

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a component's framework and I need a mechanism to add styles to an element from different directives, and they should accumulate (the order they are applied should be defined by the directive  creator  (directive the directive modifies the style))

The problem at it's core is :

```
<div ng-style="firstStyle" ng-style="secondStyle">
```

Only the first style is applied , the second one is ignored. 
I created a simple plunkr to show that only one is applied :

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cqq83V?p=preview

. Is there an easy solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it this way:

```
$scope.firstStyle ="background-color:lightblue";
$scope.secondStyle ="color:red";
```

and then:

```
<div style="{{firstStyle}};{{secondStyle}}">
  aaa
</div>
```

[works here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUkwed4oQHN3I7EAdZS6?p=preview)

Comment: that {{secondStyle}} comes from another directive . The solution I am currently implementing is tto apply the style inside a watch on that other directive like : element.css(myTwoWayBindedModel)

Comment: There is no directive at all in your example. Do you mean a second controller?

Comment: I meant: No custom directive.

Comment: I think I asked the question a bit misleading. I have a directive that has the ui, and other directives that contribute to the styles of that ui directive.

Comment: I realy like to help you, but i can't guess the issue from your descriptions. Maybe show some more code in your plunker.

Comment: The thing is that it it not about the code it is about contributing a a style to an element from a directive without a template to a directive with a template